# Ansible: understanding a compound conditional when statement

Tags: ansible

Consider this trivial ansible playbook and associated output below. Why
does task 5 get executed? These tasks were run against debian. Task 1
fails as expected. So, why does and'ing it with
'ansible_lsb.major_release|int < 14' make it true? Does this have 
something to do with operator precedence?

-jk

```
---
- name: These tests run against debian
  hosts: frontend001
  vars:
    - bcbio_dir: /mnt/bcbio
    - is_ubuntu: "'{{ansible_distribution}}' == 'Ubuntu'"
    - is_debian: "'{{ansible_distribution}}' == 'Debian'"
  tasks:
    - name: 1. Expect skip because test is_ubuntu
      debug: msg="ansible distribution - {{ansible_distribution}}, release - {{ansible_distribution_release}}, {{ ansible_lsb.major_release }}"
      when: is_ubuntu 

    - name: 2. Expect to print msg because test is_debian
      debug: msg="ansible distribution - {{ansible_distribution}}, release - {{ansible_distribution_release}}, {{ ansible_lsb.major_release }}"
      when: is_debian

    - name: 3. Expect to print msg because release 7 of wheezy
      debug: msg="ansible distribution - {{ansible_distribution}}, release - {{ansible_distribution_release}}, {{ ansible_lsb.major_release }}"
      when:  ansible_lsb.major_release|int < 14

    - name: 4. Expect to print msg because true and true is true
      debug: msg="ansible distribution - {{ansible_distribution}}, release - {{ansible_distribution_release}}, {{ ansible_lsb.major_release }}"
      when: is_debian and ansible_lsb.major_release|int < 14

    - name: 5. Expect to skip because false and true is false
      debug: msg="ansible distribution - {{ansible_distribution}}, release - {{ansible_distribution_release}}, {{ ansible_lsb.major_release }}"
      when: is_ubuntu and ansible_lsb.major_release|int < 14 


$ ansible-playbook -i ~/.elasticluster/storage/ansible-inventory.jkcluster  zbcbio.yml 

PLAY [These tests run against debian] ***************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [frontend001]

TASK: [1. Expect skip because test is_ubuntu] ********************************* 
skipping: [frontend001]

TASK: [2. Expect to print msg because test is_debian] ************************* 
ok: [frontend001] => {
    "msg": "ansible distribution - Debian, release - wheezy, 7"
}

TASK: [3. Expect to print msg because release 7 of wheezy] ******************** 
ok: [frontend001] => {
    "msg": "ansible distribution - Debian, release - wheezy, 7"
}

TASK: [4. Expect to print msg because true and true is true] ****************** 
ok: [frontend001] => {
    "msg": "ansible distribution - Debian, release - wheezy, 7"
}

TASK: [5. Expect to skip because false and true is false] ********************* 
ok: [frontend001] => {
    "msg": "ansible distribution - Debian, release - wheezy, 7"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
frontend001                : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**Edited**: 
Listing the changes based on tedder42's answer below in case someone is following along at home.

1) Changed

```
- is_ubuntu: "'{{ansible_distribution}}' == 'Ubuntu'"
```

to

```
- is_ubuntu: "{{ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'}}"
```

2) change

```
when: is_ubuntu and ansible_lsb.major_release|int < 14
```

to

```
when: is_ubuntu|bool and ansible_lsb.major_release|int < 14
```

That did it!

-jk

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TLDR: your variable is being output as a string, not evaluated. Fix the evaluation using jinja2 and then filter the var as `|bool`.

### Debugging

You're only missing one thing to debug this problem. Here's what I ran on my local OSX box:

```
- name: stackoverflow 26188055
  hosts: local
  vars:
    - bcbio_dir: /mnt/bcbio
    - is_ubuntu: "'{{ansible_distribution}}' == 'Ubuntu'"
    - is_debian: "'{{ansible_distribution}}' == 'Debian'"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=is_ubuntu
    - debug: var=is_debian
    - debug: msg="this shows the conditional passes even though it shouldnt"
      when: is_ubuntu and true
```

And the output:

```
TASK: [debug var=is_ubuntu] *************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "is_ubuntu": "'MacOSX' == 'Ubuntu'"
}

TASK: [debug var=is_debian] *************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "is_debian": "'MacOSX' == 'Debian'"
}

TASK: [debug msg="this shows the conditional passes even though it shouldnt"] *** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "this shows the conditional passes even though it shouldnt"
}
```

### Evaluating

As far as I know, you can't really evaluate down to a boolean. Typically this is done by unrolling the variable (placing it in every "when"). However, it can be accomplished as you can get a boolean as a string, then cast it to a bool [as hinted on the Variables ansible page](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html) (search for "boolean value").

```
- name: stackoverflow 26188055
  hosts: local
  vars:
    - bcbio_dir: /mnt/bcbio
    - is_ubuntu: "{{ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'}}"
    - is_debian: "{{ansible_distribution == 'Debian'}}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=is_ubuntu
    - debug: var=is_debian
    - debug: msg="this shows the conditional passes even though it shouldnt"
      when: is_ubuntu|bool and true
```

And here's the output.

```
TASK: [debug var=is_ubuntu] *************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "is_ubuntu": "False"
}

TASK: [debug var=is_debian] *************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "is_debian": "False"
}

TASK: [debug msg="this shows the conditional passes even though it shouldnt"] *** 
skipping: [127.0.0.1]
```

### Version comparison filter

Note you may want to take advantage of [Ansible's version_compare filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#version-comparison-filters). Usage is left as an exercise to the reader.